# Redshift Time Compare

Tags: sql, timestamp, amazon-redshift

I am trying to select just the traffic data in the morning and afternoon peak.
When querying data between times (as in traffic peak hour) in Amazon Redshift I couldn't get the sql:

```
    TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(timestamp_field,'HH24:MI'),'HH21:MI')) between '0001-01-01 06:30' and '0001-01-01 09:30
```

to work. It didn't return anything.
Instead, I had to use:

```
EXTRACT(HOUR from timestamp_field) = 6 and EXTRACT(MINUTE from timestamp_field) between 30 and 59
OR EXTRACT(HOUR from timestamp_field) between 7 and 8
OR EXTRACT(HOUR from timestamp_field) = 9 and EXTRACT(MINUTE from timestamp_field) between 0 and 30
```

Surely there must be an easier way?

Sample input:

```
collection_start_time
---------------------
  2015-10-30 00:00:00
  2015-10-30 00:15:00
  2015-10-30 00:30:00
  2015-10-30 00:45:00
  2015-10-30 01:00:00
  2015-10-30 01:15:00
  2015-10-30 01:30:00
  2015-10-30 01:45:00
  2015-10-30 02:00:00
  2015-10-30 02:15:00
```

Comment: John, can you copy some data from the timestamp_field here so we can test it in aws?

Comment: @JohnM . . . It would be really helpful if you described the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare you must do it with correct data types. In your first example you are comparing timestamp with string. To work it correcty you must convert strings to timestamp same way you are creating timestamp in first place:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(to_char(timestamp_field, 'HH24:MI'), 'HH24:MI') between to_timestamp('06:30', 'HH24:MI') and to_timestamp('09:30', 'HH24:MI')
```

Or even more simple, just convert it to strings and compare as strings. It will work as long as your range don't cross do other day:

```
to_char(created_at, 'HH24:MI') between '06:30' and '09:30'
```